# Is there a way I can find out where my error is?

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to create Verilog code to then generate a stopwatch on Hneemann's Digital, but I'm getting some errors. There is no indication as to where my mistakes are so I can't know for certain where to look for them. I'll post the code below to see if anyone can spot it.

```
module cronometro(

    input clk,
    input rst,
    input [6:0] minuto,
    input start,
    output [6:0] m1,
    output [6:0] m2,
    output [6:0] s3,
    output [6:0] s4

);

parameter q0 = 3'd0,  q1 = 3'd1, q2 = 3'd2, q3 = 3'd3, q4 = 3'd4, q5 = 3'd5;

    reg [7:0] a, b, n;
    reg [7:0] snA, snB, snN;
    reg [2:0] cs, ns;

    

always @(*)
begin
   case(cs)

            q0: ns = q1; 
            q1: ns = a!= n? q2:q6;
            q2: ns = q3;
            q3: ns = b!=8'd60? q2:q4;
            q4:ns = q1;
            q5: ns = q5;
            default: begin
                ns = q0; 
            end
    endcase

         always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(rst)
            cs <= q0;
        else 
            cs <= ns;
        end

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        a <= snA;
        b <= snB;
    end

 always @(*) begin

        if (enabled) begin
        case(cs)

            q0: begin
                snA = 8'd0;  
                snB = 8'd0;  
                snN = minuto;            
            end

            q1: begin
                snA = a;  
                snB = b;  
                snN = minuto; 
            end
            
            q2: begin
                snA = a;  
                snB = b + 8'd1; 
                snN = minuto;  
            end
            
            q3: begin
                snA = a;  
                snB = b;  
                snN = minuto; 
            end
            
            q4: begin
                snA = a + 8'd1;  
                snB = 8'd0;  
                snN = minuto; 
            end
            
            q5: begin
                snA = a;  
                snB = b; 
                snN = minuto;  
            end
            

            default: begin
                snA = 8'd0;  
                snB = 8'd0; 
                snN = minuto;
            end
        endcase 
        end
    end

end

endmodule
```

The errors are:

**jdoodle.v:37: syntax error**

**jdoodle.v:39: Syntax in assignment statement l-value.**

**jdoodle.v:40: syntax error**

**jdoodle.v:41: Syntax in assignment statement l-value.**

**jdoodle.v:100: syntax error**

**I give up.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got several compile errors due to the following:

- Mismatched `begin/end` due to inconsistent indentation.
- Undeclared signals: `enabled`, `q6`
- Lack of whitespace around `?` operators.

When you don't understand error messages, try your code on other simulators, such as the ones on **edaplayground**.

This code compiles without errors for me:

```
module cronometro(

    input clk,
    input rst,
    input [6:0] minuto,
    input start,
    output [6:0] m1,
    output [6:0] m2,
    output [6:0] s3,
    output [6:0] s4

);

parameter q0 = 3'd0,  q1 = 3'd1, q2 = 3'd2, q3 = 3'd3, q4 = 3'd4, q5 = 3'd5;

    reg [7:0] a, b, n;
    reg [7:0] snA, snB, snN;
    reg [2:0] cs, ns;

reg enabled, q6;

always @(*)
begin
   case(cs)

            q0: ns = q1; 
            q1: ns = a != n ? q2 : q6;
            q2: ns = q3;
            q3: ns = b != 8'd60 ? q2 : q4;
            q4:ns = q1;
            q5: ns = q5;
            default: begin
                ns = q0; 
            end
    endcase
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
        if(rst)
            cs <= q0;
        else 
            cs <= ns;
end

always @(posedge clk) begin
    a <= snA;
    b <= snB;
end

always @(*) begin

        if (enabled) begin
        case(cs)

            q0: begin
                snA = 8'd0;  
                snB = 8'd0;  
                snN = minuto;            
            end

            q1: begin
                snA = a;  
                snB = b;  
                snN = minuto; 
            end
            
            q2: begin
                snA = a;  
                snB = b + 8'd1; 
                snN = minuto;  
            end
            
            q3: begin
                snA = a;  
                snB = b;  
                snN = minuto; 
            end
            
            q4: begin
                snA = a + 8'd1;  
                snB = 8'd0;  
                snN = minuto; 
            end
            
            q5: begin
                snA = a;  
                snB = b; 
                snN = minuto;  
            end
            

            default: begin
                snA = 8'd0;  
                snB = 8'd0; 
                snN = minuto;
            end
        endcase 
        end
end

endmodule
```